# Conditional Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to have spring security that should be configurable through a boolean flag- switch on/off kind of functionality.

For example,

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server...">
<property name="interceptors">
<list>
----> Here I would like an if condition test based on external property i.e. if true, register the interceptor, else do nothing
   <ref local="wsSecurityInterceptor">
--> other interceptors like logging etc.
</list>
</property>
</bean>
```

Is this possible in config.xml? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Spring 3.1, you may try using new feature called Profile. [An Example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-31-environment-profiles)

Let me know, if you need more details on it.

Comment: That appears to be relevant to this sort of discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below added snipped:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="isAuthenticated() and #{SAMLUtil.isStateOne()}" />
```

where #{boolean_function}